# Expression recursion level exceeded error in shel script

Tags: bash

I'm a newbie to shell scripts so I have a question. What Im doing wrong in this code?

```
    #!/bin/bash

doc=testfile.csv
res=result_filtered
tmp3=tmp3

for a in $doc
do
    cut -d ";" -f 1,4 $a --output-delimiter=';'> tmp1
    cut -d ";" -f 2 tmp1 > tmp2
    cut -d "/" -f 1 tmp2 > $tmp3

        if [[ $tmp3 -gt 23 ]]
        then
            Echo "New good cluster"
            tmp1 >> $res
        fi
    rm tmp1 tmp2 tmp3
done
```

Im trying to take the information from this file:

```
block-position;chunk-position;blockSize;chunkSize
0,0;0c0,0c0;7203/49660;21/160
16,0;1c0,0c0;6458/49660;18/160
16,16;1c0,1c0;6311/49660;20/160
0,16;0c0,1c0;7261/49660;22/160
-16,16;-1c0,1c0;6890/49660;24/160
-16,0;-1c0,0c0;7143/49660;22/160
-16,-16;-1c0,-1c0;6434/49660;21/160
0,-16;0c0,-1c0;6688/49660;20/160
16,-16;1c0,-1c0;6334/49660;18/160
```

And the script basicly have to take a row it the last value is 23/160 or more

The output of the scrip shuod be a file that tel me the coordinates (the first two numbers 0,0) and the chunkSize the last value

Im geting this error mensage but I dont now how to interpretate it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5S6N.png)

I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrong. If someone could tell me how to fix it I would be thankful, sorry for my poor English I hope you guys can understand me.

Comment: Your code could likely be a lot simpler.  For the input you show, please show your corresponding desired output.

Comment: Why did you tag this `PowerShell` ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sed 's/.*;//g;s/\/.*//g' < testfile.csv | awk 'NR>1 && $0 > 23 {print "New good cluster" , $0}'
```

Demo:

```
$sed 's/.*;//g;s/\/.*//g' < temp.txt | awk 'NR>1 && $0 > 23 {print "New good cluster" , $0}'
New good cluster 24
$cat temp.txt 
block-position;chunk-position;blockSize;chunkSize
0,0;0c0,0c0;7203/49660;21/160
16,0;1c0,0c0;6458/49660;18/160
16,16;1c0,1c0;6311/49660;20/160
0,16;0c0,1c0;7261/49660;22/160
-16,16;-1c0,1c0;6890/49660;24/160
-16,0;-1c0,0c0;7143/49660;22/160
-16,-16;-1c0,-1c0;6434/49660;21/160
0,-16;0c0,-1c0;6688/49660;20/160
16,-16;1c0,-1c0;6334/49660;18/160
$
```

Explanation:

`sed 's/.*;//g;` <-- remove everything from start of line till  `;`

`s/\/.*//g'` <-- remove everything from `/` till end of line.

`\/` <-- escape char. Means take literal meaning

`NR>1`   <-- NR is `awk` internal variable that hold row number. We are removing file header

`$0`  <-- Entire input record

Comment: Hi thanks for helping,
One more thing
I also need the fist part of the file somethink like "New Cluster at 0,0 with 21

I came up with this:

`sed 's/;.*//g' < testfile.csv | sed 's/.*;//g;s/\/.*//g' < testfile.csv |  awk 'NR>1 && $1 > 23 {print "Cluster at" , $0 , "with" , $1}'`

But the result is: 
Cluster at 24 with 24

I didn't know the sed command existed but now I love it it's very useful and I can see myself wearing it if it wasn't a newbie